# How to echo an input button together with CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Need help in echo a input button alongside with css. This does not work somehow.

```
echo "<input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  inside the echo code is wrong. You should not write a  inside  tag. That is why you get an error.

Take away the  from your id will do the trick, like the below code:

```
echo "<input type='button' name='add_to_cart' id='".$row['id']."' style='margin- 
top:5px;' class='btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart' value='Add to Cart' />";
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
echo "<input type='button' name='add_to_cart' id='".$row['id']."' style='margin-top:5px;' class='btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart' value='Add to Cart' />";
```

Comment: Glad to help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

// Use following code:

```
echo "<input type='button' name='add_to_cart' id='". $row['id'] ."' style='margin-top:5px;' class='btn btn-warning form-control add_to_cart' value='Add to Cart' />";
```